# Powershell output to custom columns

Tags: powershell

Hope all is well.

Trying to see if this possible.

Task: I have list of AD group that I need find members of each group. Only get the list active users.

Issue: I wanted to see if I can put the name of the group as Column name and Group Members under each column. Not sure if this possible. So far. I was only able to use Write-Output - Group and add extra line in way to difference each group.

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path C:\Source\Listofusers.csv


$results = Foreach ($datauser in $data) 
{


$getadgroupmember = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $datauser.ADGroups -Recursive | ? {$_.objectclass -eq "user"}
write-output "`n"
write-output $datauser.ADGroups
write-output "-----------------------------------------------------------------"

foreach ($activeanddisabledusers in $getadgroupmember) 
{
Get-ADUser -Identity $activeanddisabledusers -Properties enabled | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq 'true'} | Select-Object  -ExpandProperty SamAccountName}
}
```

Comment: So you want the object to expand horizontally instead of vertically, each group will have their own column. How are you planning to filter or sort this object after ?

Comment: I have created the groups another domain and i need to import the users based on group name

Comment: That doesnt answer my question

Comment: I hoping put the output into a variable use it pull the columns one by one.